# Redirect to another folder other than cakephp application

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I have my cakephp application inside **Myproject** folder which I can access by using domain name eg. www.example.com. This website works properly.

But I have another folder called **Webservices** which contain web services written in php.
I have placed this folder inside **Myproject** folder & and trying to access php script inside **Webservices** folder by using domain name **www.example.com/weservices/phpscript.php** but it gives error that controller not found.

I have made changes in .htaccess file but I am not able to reach the solution.

below is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

I am sure that we have to make changes in .htaccess file.
can you please help me to write .htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put your *Webservices* folder inside your app's webroot so that it can be accessed (this would be the easiest solution):-

```
app/webroot/Webservices
```

Anything outside of Cake's webroot is intentionally not accessible via the browser for security and messing with your *.htaccess* file to make it accessible may lead to you accidentally creating an unwanted vulnerability.

Files/Folders in the webroot can be accessed from the browser as if they were in the root (assuming you have Cake correctly configured on your web server). So your script would be accessible at:-

```
www.example.com/Webservices/phpscript.php
```